# Php showing resource id and errors

Tags: php, mysql

Whenever I run this code, I get a resource id. How do I fix this:

```
function ct()
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `Quantity` FROM `shopping cart` WHERE `Customer_id`=1") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_fetch_array($result);   
    echo "$result";
}
```

Comment: PTEM (peruse the excellent manual) for how to use the mysql extension: http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php Also don't miss http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php.

Comment: because it return resource id by which you can fetch data. you need to pass this variable in mysql_fetch_* to get data.

Comment: go to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and check the what this function returns.

Comment: since you are using mysql_fetch_array it will return array so specify the field name

Comment: @Dewfer Fevsvfre please try my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fetch result by `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc`

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

and

> what [**`mysql_query`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) return is
>
> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

---

After edit in question

This `mysql_fetch_array($result);` Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead. So you must assigned that array to any variable to use like

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
 echo $row ['field_name'];
}
```

Or

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); // want to fetch only one row 
 echo $row ['field_name'];
```

Comment: success i did not place a field name

Answer (score -1):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("HOSTNAME", "USERNAME", "PASS", "DBNAME");    
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT `Quantity` FROM `shopping cart` WHERE `Customer_id`=1") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['Quantity'];
    echo "<br />";
}
mysqli_close($con);
```